# Wie soll ich sagen ''audit a class/course''? Vielleicht "einen Kurs anhören”？

Tags: english-to-german

Auf Englisch bedeutet *to audit a class/course*, dass ich ohne registriert zu sein (d.h. ich bekomme keine Benotung/keinen Schein) an einem Kurs teilnehme und zuhöre.

Ich möchte eine Sprachschule fragen, ob ich im Voraus einen Kurs 'auditen' dürfte, bevor ich mich entscheide, diesen Kurs zu belegen oder nicht.

Wie soll ich diese Frage formulieren?

Comment: Audit im technischen Sinn beschreibt das Ansehen und Einschätzen eines neuen Prozesses (beispielweise einer Produktion). Wenn die Firma das (zB von einem Kunden durchgeführte) Audit "besteht", kann die Produktion starten.

Answer (score 8):

Mein Vorschlag:

- Kann ich an einer kostenlosen Probestunde teilnehmen?
- Bieten Sie unverbindliche Probestunden an?
- Bieten Sie kostenlosen Testunterricht an?

Einige Beispiele: [1](https://www.sprachschule-aktiv.de/stuttgart/probestunde/),       [2](https://www.berlitz.com/de-ch/kostenlose-probestunde),  [3](https://www.lichtenberger-sprachinstitut.de/sprachkurs-probestunde.html), [4](https://www.iq-wissen.de/iq/sprachkurse-2/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIy83MlZmm7wIVGuR3Ch2zaAkNEAMYAiAAEgIRXPD_BwE).

Answer (score 3):

Einen Kurs, oder eher eine Vorlesung "hören" wird vor allem bei einem Studium an einer Universität verwendet:

> Ich höre *Zoologie der Wirbeltiere* bei Professor Müller.

An anderen Lehreinrichtungen, wie Schule, Volkshochschulen oder Sprachschulen, ist diese Formulierung nicht üblich. Dort spricht man eher davon, dass man einen Kurs "besucht"

> Ich besuche einen Französisch-Kurs an der Volkshochschule.

oder den Kurs einfach "macht"

> Ich mache nächstes Wochenende einen Fotografie-Kurs, darum habe ich Samstags nachmittags keine Zeit.

Für den englischen Begriff "audit" gibt es keine etablierte einheitliche Übersetzung. Je nach Kontext verwendet man unterschiedliche Verben, zum Beispiel "prüfen", "inspizieren", "sichten".

Im geschilderten Kontext würde ich eine Formulierung mit "Probe" oder "probieren" wählen. Das könnte etwas sein wie

> Ich würde gerne den Deutsch-Kurs ausprobieren.

> Kann ich für ein paar Tage zur Probe am Deutsch-Kurs teilnehmen?

Comment: Die Verwendung von "hören" in Bezug auf Universitätsvorlesungen stimmt zwar, jedoch sollte hier ein gewisser Bedeutungsunterschied zum angelsächsischen Raum beachtet werden: Im deutschsprachigen Raum ist es an den meisten Universitäten kein Problem (bzw. Studenten sogar explizit empfohlen), sich einfach in beliebige Vorlesungen hineinzusetzen und sie "zu hören". Man benötigt dazu keine Registrierung oder Ähnliches - diese Registrierung, um einen Schein zu bekommen und/oder an Prüfungen zur Vorlesung teilzunehmen, ist zumeist unabhängig von der eigentlichen Vorlesung (also dem Vortrag) selber.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke, die Nachfrage zu einer

- Teilnahme als temporärer Gasthörer

oder eine

- Probestunde

wäre hier die richtige Wortwahl